# How to get last inserted ids in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am inserting multiple rows at the same time, say 2 rows

```
$multiple_rows = [
    ['email' => 'taylor@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
    ['email' => 'dayle@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
];
DB::table('users')->insert($multiple_rows);
```

How can I get those inserted ids.

I am doing it, this way for now.

```
foreach($multiple_rows as $row){
  DB::table('users')->insert($row);
  $record_ids[] = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
}
```

Any other good way to do it, without inserting single row each time.

Comment: How are you inserting the data? Is it coming from a form? If you knew how many rows were being inserted each time then you could just order by the `created_at` column descending and take the required amount of rows.

Comment: try with `insertGetId()`

Comment: @James No, number of rows are dynamic, It can be 1-20.

Comment: @yahoo Can you provide me complete syntax for insertGetId() for multiple rows, actually I tried but its giving me error :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
$latestUser = DB::table('users')->select('id')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();

$multiple_rows = [
    ['email' => 'taylor@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
    ['email' => 'dayle@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
];

DB::table('users')->insert($multiple_rows);

$users = DB::table('users')->select('id')->where('id', '>', $latestUser->id)->get();
```

Comment: And what if somebody executes the same request in parallel? The last one will receive more ids than expected, including the ones inserted by the parallel requests.

Comment: Most use cases are covered by internal locking methods generating a queue process, but there are plenty of other ways to handle that. Which would be a separate question.

Answer (score 5):

If you really need all the inserted ID's

```
$dataArray = [
    ['name' => 'ABC'],
    ['name' => 'DEF']
];

$ids = [];

foreach($dataArray as $data)
{
     $ids[] = DB::table('posts')->insertGetId($data);

}
```

To get all id with a massive insertion I think the good way is to first get the last id in the table, make the massive insertion and get the last id. In theory they must follow, unless there has been an insertion from another connection. To avoid that the solution is a **[transaction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#database-transactions)**.

**Update**

Also read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#inserts)