# Bulk insert and get returned ids laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an array like this one :

```
 0 => array:2 [
    "name" => "Data1"
    "type" => "value1"
  ],
 1 => array:2 [
    "name" => "Data2"
    "type" => "value2"
  ]
```

i want to insert them in single query in the database and retrieve their ids without any additional query.

So far i have tried `insertGetId`

```
MyModel::insertGetId($array)
```

but i have noticed it inserts bulk rows but return the last id.

Comment: Create custom method. Any problem with this ?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35524376/3584881) it might help you, there is no in-built code to get IDs, so you've to do custom code like that link.

Comment: You can see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065317/laravel-multi-insert-rows-and-retrive-ids

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik three quires er user? , i think its a lot when the project scale

Comment: @wahdan I've thought, aboute looping through each insert and collect ids in array and finally return that array. That's not optimal solution for this :D

Comment: I think one solution could be, with last id returned, we have total no of records inserted. If you are using sql then increment id up to number of records inserted, then you will get result in one incrementing loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well You Can Get The Last Id from the table .. Then After The Insertion Add The Last id To The Count of your array .. But you Will face a problem and that is if you have 2 or more users inserted some records into this table at the same time .. so you can use The Transaction

```
 try{
    DB::beginTransaction();

   // 1- get the last id of your table ($lastIdBeforeInsertion)

   // 2- insert your data
    Model::insert($array);

  // 3- Getting the last inserted ids
  $insertedIds = [];
  for($i=1; $i<=theCountOfTheArray; $i++)
     array_push($insertedIds, $lastIdBeforeInsertion+$i);

});

    DB::commit();
}catch(\Exception $e){
    DB::rollback();
}
```

or

```
DB::transaction(function() {

   // 1- get the last id of your table ($lastIdBeforeInsertion)

   // 2- insert your data
   Model::insert($array);

  // 3- Getting the last inserted ids
  $insertedIds = [];
  for($i=1; $i<=theCountOfTheArray; $i++)
     array_push($insertedIds, $lastIdBeforeInsertion+$i);

});
```

[Database Transaction Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#database-transactions)

[Very Useful Article About Database Transactions](http://fideloper.com/laravel-database-transactions)

### Edit

You Can make a unique Column and Call it for Example `unique_bulk_id` .. This will hold randomly generated string for the inserted data .. after the insertion you can get the inserted data by This `unique_bulk_id`.

Comment: Saying 'make a unique Column' sounds too ambiguous, people will think make a column with a unique constraint, which woulld clearly not work.

Comment: `$lastIdBeforeInsertion` may not be a source of truth. When the last record is deleted it create a gap. Example : Your last record has the ID 23, you delete it, your last id will be 22 but your next record will have the ID 24.

Answer (score 3):

As I commented in @ali-beshir's answer;

> `$lastIdBeforeInsertion` may not be a source of truth. When the last
> record is deleted it create a gap. Example : Your last record has the
> ID 23, you delete it, your last id will be 22 but your next record
> will have the ID 24.

So I did by getting the last ID only which is, I think, more reliable.

```php
DB::transaction(function() {

    Model::insert($data);
   
    $lastId = Model::orderByDesc('id')->first()->id;

    $ids = range($lastId - count($data) + 1, $lastId);

});
```