# Retrive Bulk Inserted ids after insert() function in Laravel 6+

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I Research a lot but Could not find any solution. So i am posting it Here
My problem is After Inserting bulk rows i want to get all the inserted ids to save the ids to another Pivot table.. Here is my code

```
$create_market = [];
                $create_market_possibility = [];
                foreach ($request->type0 as $key => $value) {
                    array_push($create_market, [
                        'market_id' => $value['market_id'],
                        'event_id' => $value['event_id'],
                        'name' => $value['name'],
                        'bet_min' => $value['min_bet'],
                        'bet_max' => $value['max_bet'],
                        'commission' => $value['commission'],
                        'type' => 0,
                        'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
                        'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()
                    ]);
                }
                foreach ($request->type1 as $key => $value1) {
                    array_push($create_market, [
                        'market_id' => $value1['market_id'],
                        'event_id' => $value1['event_id'],
                        'name' => $value1['name'],
                        'bet_min' => $value1['min_bet'],
                        'bet_max' => $value1['max_bet'],
                        'commission' => $value1['commission'],
                        'type' => 1,
                        'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
                        'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()
                    ]);
                    foreach ($value1['possibility'] as $key => $value2) {
                        array_push($create_market_possibility, [

                            // because i am not getting the inserted ids here i cant push it here
                            // that is the problem i am facing 

                            'market_id' => $value1['market_id'],
                            'event_id' => $value1['event_id'],
                            'possibility' => $value2['possibility'],
                            'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
                            'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()
                        ]);
                    }
                }
                Market::insert($create_market);
                // Here i want to retrive the last inserted all ids and put then in the obj of
                  [$create_market_possibility] array ... 

                if(count($create_market_possibility) > 0) {
                    MarketPossibility::insert($create_market_possibility);
                }
                $response = [
                    'status' => true,
                    'message' => 'Market Successfully Created'
                ];
                return response()->json($response); //@ sending response
```

i did this thing wher i was using create() for single insert 
`$id = Market::create($array)`

It was returning me the object.. But in this case i have to insert multiple rows..
If there any other way to do it please let me know , Thank You!

Comment: Have you tried `$create_market_possibility = Market::insert($create_market)`

Comment: You are saying to save the object in create_market_possibility array ??... I tried  this but it returning me 1

Answer (score 1):

## 1. For type0

You can run Market::insert($array) for type0 since there is no associated MarketPossibility

## 2. For type1,

You will have to create each Market one by one then associate it - you can use `saveMany()` to make it cleaner a faster:

```
$market = Market::create([...])

$new_market_possibility = [];
foreach ($value1['possibility'] as $key => $value2) {
    $new_market_possibility[] = new App\MarketPossibility([...]);
}

$market->marketPossibilities()->saveMany($new_market_possibilities);
```

All that assuming that you have standard relations in place between Market and MarketPossibility

Comment: ` $market = Market::create([...]) ` will work for multiple insert?? Coz market is also inserting multiple

Comment: for a single market only since you have to run the association per market

Comment: Since the request data is an array.. Then i have to run the query under a loop that is i am not looking for

Comment: Well, I'm not sure you can achieve what you want in a single command since you won't be able to get the ids from your Market

Comment: Thats the problem.. Is there any way to get the ids after insert() method

Comment: not as far as I know, since it is simply executing a database query that doesn't return the ids.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039765/bulk-insert-and-get-returned-ids-laravel/46045642 for some clues