# Laravel 6: Bulk Insert With Bulk Insert Relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have table `itineraries`, `meals` and `itinerary_meal`.

`Itineraries` have many to many relations with the `meals` table.

When upon `dd($request->all())`, it provides me with the value:

```
"product_itineraries" => array:3 [▼
    1 => array:6 [▼
      "itinerary_title_en" => "123123"
      "itinerary_title_th" => "123123"
      "day_number" => "1"
      "itinerary_description_en" => null
      "itinerary_description_th" => null
      "meal_type_id" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "1"
        1 => "2"
        2 => "3"
      ]
    ]
```

I am able to bulk insert Itinerary like:

```
foreach ($request->product_itineraries as $product_itinerariesKey => $product_itineraries) {
    if (empty($product_itineraries)) {
        continue;
    }
    $productItineraryData[$product_itinerariesKey]['meal_type_id'] = $product_itineraries['meal_type_id'];
    $productItineraryData[$product_itinerariesKey]['product_id'] = $product->id;
    $productItineraryData[$product_itinerariesKey]['itinerary_title_en'] = $product_itineraries['itinerary_title_en'];
    $productItineraryData[$product_itinerariesKey]['itinerary_title_th'] = $product_itineraries['itinerary_title_th'];
    $productItineraryData[$product_itinerariesKey]['day_number'] = $product_itineraries['day_number'];
    $productItineraryData[$product_itinerariesKey]['itinerary_description_en'] = $product_itineraries['itinerary_description_en'];
    $productItineraryData[$product_itinerariesKey]['itinerary_description_th'] = $product_itineraries['itinerary_description_th'];
    $productItineraryData[$product_itinerariesKey]['created_at'] = $nowTime;
    $productItineraryData[$product_itinerariesKey]['updated_at'] = $nowTime;
}

if (!empty($productItineraryData) && count($productItineraryData) > 0) {
    ProductItinerary::insert($productItineraryData);
}
```

Using that, I am now unable to bulk insert related meal_type since I do not get **product itinerary id**.
Also I am not getting Model of Product Itinerary so unable to save using meals() relation

Is there any solution to bulk insert model and its relation?

Comment: Consider insertGetId() as https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#inserts

Comment: @KurtFriars It provides me an error saying `Array to string conversion` when using `insertGetId($productItineraryData)` when `insert($productItineraryData)` works fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: I do not think insertGetId works for bulk insert @KurtFriars

Comment: You are correct. My appologies. Interesting solution here using db transactions. Essentially once you know the first id you inserted and the number of records you are inserting you know all the ids. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039765/bulk-insert-and-get-returned-ids-laravel/46045642

Comment: Yes @KurtFriars , this seems to be one of the solutions. Thank you. But in my case, the request has nested array for single model, so it is little bit difficult to pull off the related id and nested array at the same time. Seem like the reasonable solution I found is not to use bulk insertion for this situation.

Comment: Is meal_type_id the id of meal on the meals table?

Comment: Yes @KurtFriars

Comment: I just made an important update, if you are testing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some assumptions about the structure of your data, and table/column names, let me know if this achieves the bulk inserting you were looking for:

```
$itineraries = [];
$relatedMeals = [];

foreach ($request->product_itineraries as $product_itinerariesKey => $product_itineraries) {
    if (empty($product_itineraries)) {
        continue;
    }

    $itinerary['product_id'] = $product->id;
    $itinerary['itinerary_title_en'] = $product_itineraries['itinerary_title_en'];
    $itinerary['itinerary_title_th'] = $product_itineraries['itinerary_title_th'];
    $itinerary['day_number'] = $product_itineraries['day_number'];
    $itinerary['itinerary_description_en'] = $product_itineraries['itinerary_description_en'];
    $itinerary['itinerary_description_th'] = $product_itineraries['itinerary_description_th'];
    $itinerary['created_at'] = $nowTime;
    $itinerary['updated_at'] = $nowTime;

    $itineraries[] = $itinerary;
    $relatedMeals[] = $product_itineraries['meal_type_id'];
}

DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    $itineraryId = ProductItinerary::sharedLock()->max('id') + 1;
    ProductItinerary::insert($itineraries);

    $relations = [];
    foreach ($relatedMeals as $mealIds) {
        foreach ($mealIds as $mealId) {
            $relations[] = [
                'product_itinerary_id' => $itineraryId,
                'meal_id' => $mealId,
            ];
        }
        $itineraryId++;
    }

    DB::table('product_itinerary_meal')->insert($relations);

    DB::commit();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!

Comment: @LizeshShakya Please see where I have added the sharedLock method on the query builder above, I was thinking about this last night, and it seems that transactions will not lock the table. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#pessimistic-locking