# How to get the list of inserted ids from the insert() method to use with the syncWithoutDetaching() method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have Files and Folders models that are related by a many-to-many relationship with a `folder_file` pivot table.

I want to insert files in bulk using the insert() method, then use the list of inserted ids with the syncWithoutDetaching() method to update the pivot table, | first create the $data_array in a foreach loop that does other things as well:

```
$data_array = [];
foreach (...) {
    // ...
    $data_array[] = $row;
}
```

then I want to insert the data and update the pivot table:

```
File::insert($data_array);
$folder->files()->syncWithoutDetaching($array_of_inserted_ids);
```

Is it possible to get the list of inserted ids from the `insert()` method?
Or maybe there is a more efficient way for better DB performance?

At first I just wanted to create the record and update the pivot table inside the `foreach` loop that creates the `$data_array` so that on every iteration it would create and update the tables, but that could be bad for performance with that many queries?

Comment: I think you could find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039765/bulk-insert-and-get-returned-ids-laravel

Comment: I saw it but the answer is pretty bad there and old, thought there might be an update by now :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `createMany()` here. Instead of inserting the files then get the ids of inserted data. It will accept an array of data so that you could directly insert your `array of files` then connecting them to the folder.

```
$folder->files()->createMany($data_array);
```

Comment: Nice, I guess I missed that part of the docs 