# How to get multiple auto incremented id in laravel database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on laravel database. inserting multiple data in key value array format .
But I want an id of all inserted row

```
DB::table('table')->insert('array' =>'value');
```

How can i get multiple inserted id.

Comment: I suppose there's no such functionality. Insert each record one by one.

Comment: You have to either get last id first and range after insertion , or increase by count

Comment: If last id is `10` and after insertion last id is `15` then you can make array of last ids as `[11,12,13,14,15]`

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35524376/320487